# EF June 2011 CTP Install, throws error on User Machine

Tags: entity-framework

I Installed Entity Framework June 2011 CTP and changed the target framework to "EF June 2011 CTP", it works well with my Win7 Dev Machine, but in virtual xp machine it throws this error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.File name:
>   'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check [system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26660) of EF June 2011 CTP. There is no Windows XP mentioned. Only Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Vista are supported.